# awk to print all the minimum values for each category

Tags: awk

Would like to print all the minimum values based on **$1 and $3** combinations. If there are two or more lines are available 
for minimum value having unique combinations of $1 and $3 then need to print all the lines . For example , $1-"Abc" having minimum value $3-"10" appearing two times i.e Abc,yyy,10,aaa  and  Abc,ttt,10,aaa.  Input file has not sorted on any order.

Input.txt

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,xxx,20,aaa
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
Abc,zzz,35,aaa
def,xxx,30,bbb
Abc,ttt,10,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
def,zzz,45,bbb
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
```

Would like to print the output along with header row  `NR==1 , {print}`

Desired Output.txt

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
Abc,ttt,10,aaa
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
def,yyy,20,bbb
```

I am using two commands to get the desired output, first `sort` the input file based on $1 and $3 then second command `awk -F, '!seen[$1]++'` 
Looking for your suggestions to simply like one liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An awk which processes the file twice. On the first run it picks the smallest $3 for each $1 and on the second it prints the smallest:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{FS=","}                             # delimiter
NR==FNR {                                 # first run
    if ($1 in a==0 || $3<a[$1])
        a[$1]=$3
    next
}
$3==a[$1] # || FNR==1                     # if Country is data not header
' file file                               # uncomment the FNR==1
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
Abc,ttt,10,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
```

Comment: That is a very sweet awk.

Comment: Thanks a lot James Brown

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output in same sequence as same Input_file then try following too:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print;} FNR>1 && FNR==NR{a[$1]=a[$1]>$3?$3:(a[$1]?a[$1]:$3);next} $3==a[$1]'   Input_file  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{
                print;
              }
         FNR>1 && FNR==NR{
                                a[$1]=a[$1]>$3?$3:(a[$1]?a[$1]:$3);
                                next
                         }
         $3==a[$1]
        '   Input_file   Input_file
```

**EDIT2:** Adding one more solution in which we read Input_file only 1 time.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{
                print;
                next
               }
         FNR>1{
                a[$1]=a[$1]>$3?$3:(a[$1]?a[$1]:$3);
                b[$0]=$0
              }
         END  {;
                for(i in b){
                split(b[i], array,",");
                if(array[3]==a[array[1]]){
                print b[i]
                                         }
                           };
              }
        '   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 0):

If you want sorted output, you will need to have the whole file in memory (or use `sort`).

You can use ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'mins=Hash.new(2**999)
        data=Hash.new()
        options={:col_sep=>",", :headers=>true, :return_headers=>true}
        data=CSV.parse($<, **options).
                map { |r| mins[r[0]]=r[2].to_i < mins[r[0]] ? r[2].to_i : mins[r[0]]; r }
        puts data.shift.to_csv(**options)
        data.sort_by { |r| r[0] }.
                each { |r| if mins[r[0]]==r[2].to_i then puts  r.to_csv(**options) end } 
        ' file

Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
Abc,ttt,10,aaa
def,xxx,10,bbb
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
```

In this case sorted by `Country` but you could sort on any field of the csv.

You can also use `gawk` if you want a sorted version:

```
$ gawk -F"," 'FNR==1{header=$0; next} 
            {lines[FNR-1]=$0
             if ($1 in mins==0 || $3<mins[$1])
                mins[$1]=$3             
            }
    
            END{ asort(lines)
                 print header
                 for (e in lines) {
                    split(lines[e], arr, ",")
                    if (mins[arr[1]]==arr[3]) print lines[e]
                 }
            }
' file
# same output
```

With `gawk` you could write a trivial sort to sort on any key as well.