# awk to print first ( Nth rows) three minimum values for each category

Tags: awk

Would like to print `first three minimum values` based on **`$1 and $3`** combinations for each category. Input file has not sorted on any order.
Looking for your suggestions.

Input.txt

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,xxx,20,aaa
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
Abc,zzz,5,aaa
def,xxx,30,bbb
Abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
def,zzz,45,bbb
```

Would like to print the output along with header row  `NR==1 , {print}`

Desired Output.txt

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,zzz,5,aaa
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
Abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
def,xxx,30,bbb
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awk to print all the minimum values for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652786/awk-to-print-all-the-minimum-values-for-each-category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{print (NR==1?1:2)","$0}' file |
  sort -t, -s -k1,1n -k2,2 -k4,4n |
  cut -d, -f2- |
  awk -F, 'cnt[$1]++<3'
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,zzz,5,aaa
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
Abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
def,xxx,30,bbb
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
```

The first `awk` prepends a 1 for the header line and 2 for every other line so the subsequent `sort` keeps the header line first, and then the `cut` removes that prepended value before the final `awk` operates on the original data (now sorted).

The primary benefit of the above approach vs the separate head+tail commands is you can run the above even when the input to it is coming from a pipe rather than a file since you don't have to open the input twice with 2 separate commands.

With the above approach the whole of the input file is fed to the final awk command so you can add/remove/modify fields, etc. as you'd expect. To get that same behavior with one of the head+tail approaches you'd need to group the part before the final pipe to awk in `{ }`, e.g.:

```
{ head -1 file && tail -n +2 file | sort -t, -s -k1,1 -k3,3h; } | awk -F, 'cnt[$1]++<3'
```

I'm using the `-s` for "stable sort" arg to sort, btw, so that input lines with identical $1 and $3 values are guaranteed to come out in their original order.

Comment: @ Ed Morton, Thanks a lot for the help, actual input file contains 44 columns , would like to populate all other fields information as well. Sorry forgot to mention that no of columns details in that question

Comment: @AVN OK, I don't understand why you're telling me that though as the above will work for any number of columns. Do you see a problem?

Comment: @ Ed Morton, got it, in actual input file "Amount" field column position is 22, previously  I thought supposed to write sort -t, -s -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 -k6,6 and so on -k22,22n etc

Comment: No, just increment the sort field(s) number by 1 to account for the extra leading field that the first awk is adding. So if your sort field is 22 in the original input file then it'd be 23 for the sort command (and you'd have the added -k1,1n as shown to protect the relative order of the header line vs the rest of the file).

Comment: Thank You Ed Morton

Comment: @ Ed Morton, noticed that actual input file have some repeated / duplicated rows with same minimum value. For example, if “Abc,zzz,5,aaa” entry appears 4 times in the input file , our script will output into 3 times of “Abc,zzz,5,aaa” then ignore second minimum value – “Abc,yyy,10,aaa”
And third minimum value – “Abc,ttt,15,aaa” . Kindly advise to print all the unique 3 minimum values.

Comment: Actually, they are not duplicated rows while comparing other (44) fields information.

Comment: Please post a new question if you have one with the problematic data included in your sample input/output. You can reference this one but make sure the new question stands alone.

Answer (score 1):

I would `sort` first then pipe to awk to pick the first 3 lines:

```
sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n file|awk -F, 'c!=$1{p=1;c=$1}p++<=3'
```

example:

```
kent$  cat f
Abc,xxx,20,aaa
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
Abc,zzz,5,aaa
def,xxx,30,bbb
Abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
def,zzz,45,bbb

kent$  sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n f|awk -F, 'c!=$1{p=1;c=$1}p++<=3'
Abc,zzz,5,aaa
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
Abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
def,xxx,30,bbb
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
```

You can change the `<=3` part into the desired number, you can also pass a shell variable to the awk to replace the hard coded `3`.

### update for the header line

If you want to add the header line to the top of the output, quick way is just adding `head -1 file;` or `head -1 file &&` to the line

```
head -1 file; sort.. <(tail -n +2 file)|awk...
```

If you want to redirect to some file: (like `result`)

```
head -1 file > result; sort ....<(tail -n +2 file)|awk ... >> result
```

Comment: you forgot about header **print the output along with header**

Comment: @Kent, Thanks a lot for the help,  Is there any other option other than "sort" . My actual input file in the country field having some special characters at various places like Cura‡ao and cygwin showing error like sort: string comparison failed: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were Cura‡ao

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it won't be a problem to save the header and print at the end. I understood op's main problem would be sorting and pick first 3 lines. My answer might not be the working out of box solution, but provided a solution to the main problem, I hope.

Comment: @AVN you can try changing your local (to UTF-8? for example) before launch ing the sort/awk...

Answer (score 1):

Another ***sort*** + ***awk*** solution:

```
head -1 file && sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3h <(tail -n +2 file) | awk -F, 'a[$1]++<3'
```

The output:

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
Abc,zzz,5,aaa
Abc,yyy,10,aaa
Abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
def,xxx,30,bbb
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
```