# awk to print all three unique minimum values for each category - Continuation

Tags: awk

Would like to print all three minimum values based on `$1 and $3` combinations for each category. 
For example `$1-"abc"` having unique three minimum values are `$3 - "5,10,15"` , Input file has not sorted on any order.
Looking for your suggestions.

Input.txt

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
abc,xxx,20,aaa
abc,yyy,10,aaa
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
abc,zzz,5,aaa
def,xxx,10,bbb
abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
def,zzz,30,bbb
abc,sss,5,aaa
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
def,zzz,45,bbb
abc,mmm,5,aaa
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
abc,nnn,5,aaa
ghi,xxx,60,ccc
```

Would like to print the output along with header row  `NR==1 , {print}`

Desired Output.txt

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
abc,zzz,5,aaa
abc,sss,5,aaa
abc,mmm,5,aaa
abc,nnn,5,aaa
abc,yyy,10,aaa
abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,xxx,10,bbb
def,yyy,20,bbb
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
```

***Edit#1:***

Would like to print minimum order as well . To identify the first minimum value, second minimum value, third minimum value for each category.

**Desired Output#1:**

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order
abc,mmm,5,aaa,1
abc,nnn,5,aaa,1
abc,sss,5,aaa,1
abc,zzz,5,aaa,1
abc,yyy,10,aaa,2
abc,ttt,15,aaa,3
def,xxx,10,bbb,1
def,yyy,20,bbb,2
def,zzz,30,bbb,3
ghi,ttt,25,ccc,1
ghi,yyy,25,ccc,1
ghi,xxx,35,ccc,2
ghi,zzz,50,ccc,3
```

***Edit #2:***

I have tried like this

```
{ read -r header; echo "$header"","Min_Order; sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n; } < Input.csv | awk -F, '
    $1 != prev1 {num_seen = 0; prev3 = -999}
    $3 != prev3 {num_seen++}
    num_seen <= 3 {print $0","num_seen}
    {prev1 = $1; prev3 = $3}
' > Output.csv
```

and got the ***Output#2:***

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order,1
abc,mmm,5,aaa,1
abc,nnn,5,aaa,1
abc,sss,5,aaa,1
abc,zzz,5,aaa,1
abc,yyy,10,aaa,2
abc,ttt,15,aaa,3
def,xxx,10,bbb,1
def,yyy,20,bbb,2
def,zzz,30,bbb,3
ghi,ttt,25,ccc,1
ghi,yyy,25,ccc,1
ghi,xxx,35,ccc,2
ghi,zzz,50,ccc,3
```

Please suggest to avoid one additional column in header row , would like print the header from `Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order,1` to `Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awk to print all the minimum values for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652786/awk-to-print-all-the-minimum-values-for-each-category)

Comment: You might want to mention what's different about this question from your last one and reference that last one so people reading this have something to start with and it doesn't just get closed as a dup!

Comment: Point taken , will take care in new posts. This question is different than the previous question. Here, we need to print "Top 'X' - Minimum unique values  like Top 3, Top 10 minimum unique values. previous question was to print least minimum values only

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, please remove possible duplicate

Comment: down voter, kindly let me know the reason for down vote

Comment: it wasn't me, but probably because you did not show any effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first sort the file. That will make the awk process much easier.

```
{ read -r header; echo "$header"; sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n; } < file | awk -F, '
    $1 != prev1 {num_seen = 0; prev3 = -999}
    $3 != prev3 {num_seen++}
    num_seen <= 3 {print}
    {prev1 = $1; prev3 = $3}
'
```

```
Country,Desc,Amount,Details
abc,mmm,5,aaa
abc,nnn,5,aaa
abc,sss,5,aaa
abc,zzz,5,aaa
abc,yyy,10,aaa
abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,xxx,10,bbb
def,yyy,20,bbb
def,zzz,30,bbb
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot- glenn jackman , it's working fine. Kindly advise how to print minimum order as well . To identify the first minimum value, second minimum value, third minimum value for each category. Just edited the post , expected result like "Desired Output#1:"

Comment: 'Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order
abc,mmm,5,aaa,1
abc,nnn,5,aaa,1
abc,sss,5,aaa,1
abc,zzz,5,aaa,1
abc,yyy,10,aaa,2
abc,ttt,15,aaa,3
def,xxx,10,bbb,1
def,yyy,20,bbb,2
def,zzz,30,bbb,3
ghi,ttt,25,ccc,1
ghi,yyy,25,ccc,1
ghi,xxx,35,ccc,2
ghi,zzz,50,ccc,3'

Comment: you need to print the current line and the `num_seen` variable.

Comment: glenn jackman, i have tried like this { read -r header; echo "$header"; sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n; } < Input.csv | awk -F, '
    $1 != prev1 {num_seen = 0; prev3 = -999}
    $3 != prev3 {num_seen++}
    num_seen <= 3 {print $0","num_seen}
    {prev1 = $1; prev3 = $3}
'  and got the output like this ,1untry,Desc,Amount,Details
,1c,mmm,5,aaa
,1c,nnn,5,aaa
,1c,sss,5,aaa
,1c,zzz,5,aaa
,2c,yyy,10,aaa
,3c,ttt,15,aaa
,1f,xxx,10,bbb
,2f,yyy,20,bbb
,3f,zzz,30,bbb
,1i,ttt,25,ccc
,1i,yyy,25,ccc
,2i,xxx,35,ccc
,3i,zzz,50,ccc

Comment: I hope you're realized by now you can't post formatted output in a comment. Your file has `\r\n` line endings, so you'll have to remove the `\r`. Use `dos2unix` or `sed 's/\r$//'`

Comment: Wow , superb glenn jackman, it's working fine now. how to control the "header row" as i am getting "Country,Desc,Amount,Details,1" would like to get "Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order"

Comment: glenn jackman , kindly advise on "Edit#2"  & "Output#2" format

Comment: You have asked 60 awk questions, and you can't figure that out? What's the awk variable for "the current record number"?

Comment: FNR , I did a work around like this to get the desired output , awk -F, 'NR==1 { print $0",""Min_Order"} ' Input.csv > Op_Input.csv ; sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n <(tail -n +2 Input.csv) | awk -F, '
    $1 != prev1 {num_seen = 0; prev3 = -999}
    $3 != prev3 {num_seen++}
    num_seen <= 3 {print $0","num_seen}
    {prev1 = $1; prev3 = $3}
' >> Op_Input.csv

Comment: I am from Accounting dept, most of the time work with Ms Excel (99.99%) only, rarely using script when excel is not able to perform action. Sorry if I troubled you more. Curiosity to know how easily your code might be changed

Comment: glenn jackman,another try with sed version, { read -r header; echo "$header"","Min_Order; sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n; } < Input.csv | awk -F, '
    $1 != prev1 {num_seen = 0; prev3 = -999}
    $3 != prev3 {num_seen++}
    num_seen <= 3 {print $0","num_seen}
    {prev1 = $1; prev3 = $3}
' > Output.csv | sed -i '1 s/,1//' Output.csv

Comment: OK, I appreciate your effort: use `num_seen <= 3 {print $0 FS (NR == 1 ? "Min_Order" : num_seen)}`

Comment: Thanks a ton glenn jackman , script is working like a magic :)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you a simple solution. Before that, In 3rd column(i.e Amount) its always be a better way to keep fixed length (especially if it is a number and you want to sort based on the column). So I am assuming here amount will have 2 digits. In that way, `5` will become `05` (Since I fixed the length of amount).

```
cat file
```

Input will have:

```
abc,xxx,20,aaa
abc,yyy,10,aaa
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
abc,zzz,05,aaa
def,xxx,10,bbb
abc,ttt,15,aaa
def,yyy,20,bbb
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
def,zzz,30,bbb
abc,sss,05,aaa
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
def,zzz,45,bbb
abc,mmm,05,aaa
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
abc,nnn,05,aaa
ghi,xxx,60,ccc
```

Now, The easiest way to sort this is:

```
sort -t, -b  -k1.1,1.3 -k3.1,3.2 file
```

It will print(will be your first expected output):

```
abc,mmm,05,aaa
abc,nnn,05,aaa
abc,sss,05,aaa
abc,zzz,05,aaa
abc,yyy,10,aaa
abc,ttt,15,aaa
abc,xxx,20,aaa
def,xxx,10,bbb
def,yyy,20,bbb
def,zzz,30,bbb
def,zzz,45,bbb
ghi,ttt,25,ccc
ghi,yyy,25,ccc
ghi,xxx,35,ccc
ghi,zzz,50,ccc
ghi,xxx,60,ccc
```

With the help of `awk` you can achieve your second output.

```
sort -t, -b  -k1.1,1.3 -k3.1,3.2 file | awk -F, '{OFS=","};{if(a[$1]!=$3){a[$1]=$3;cnt[$1]++}else if(!a[$1]){cnt[$1]=1}{print $0","cnt[$1]}}'
```

It will print:

```
abc,mmm,05,aaa,1
abc,nnn,05,aaa,1
abc,sss,05,aaa,1
abc,zzz,05,aaa,1
abc,yyy,10,aaa,2
abc,ttt,15,aaa,3
abc,xxx,20,aaa,4
def,xxx,10,bbb,1
def,yyy,20,bbb,2
def,zzz,30,bbb,3
def,zzz,45,bbb,4
ghi,ttt,25,ccc,1
ghi,yyy,25,ccc,1
ghi,xxx,35,ccc,2
ghi,zzz,50,ccc,3
ghi,xxx,60,ccc,4
```

I hope you were waiting for a better solution. :)

If you want to add header then:

```
sed -i '1i Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order' output
```

Comment: Abhinandan prasad, Thanks a lot for the suggestions !!! Unfortunately,  3rd column(i.e Amount) will not be fixed length as it will have various decimal places length. Up voted for your try !!!

Comment: I have tried like this "sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3n Input.csv | awk -F, '{OFS=","};{if(a[$1]!=$3){a[$1]=$3;cnt[$1]++}else if(!a[$1]){cnt[$1]=1}{print $0","cnt[$1]}}'
" and got the output , abc,mmm,5,aaa,1
abc,nnn,5,aaa,1
abc,sss,5,aaa,1
abc,zzz,5,aaa,1
abc,yyy,10,aaa,2
abc,ttt,15,aaa,3
abc,xxx,20,aaa,4
Country,Desc,Amount,Details,1
def,xxx,10,bbb,1
def,yyy,20,bbb,2
def,zzz,30,bbb,3
def,zzz,45,bbb,4
ghi,ttt,25,ccc,1
ghi,yyy,25,ccc,1
ghi,xxx,35,ccc,2
ghi,zzz,50,ccc,3
ghi,xxx,60,ccc,4

Comment: I am getting "Country,Desc,Amount,Details,1" would like to get "Country,Desc,Amount,Details,Min_Order"  , please suggest

Comment: @AVN Even it has decimal values. It will work. You just have to increase the fixed length size. Suppose you have maximum 2 decimal values in any amount. then fixed length can be increased to 5. eg `50.66` has 5 character.

Comment: Thank you , In real time scenarios, we used to receive rates from various part of the world/merchants and input file will have different length like xx.yy, xxx.yyyy, xxx.yyyyy , xx.yyyyyyy etc

Comment: @AVN Updated my answer.

Comment: @AVN I think every column will have its maximum length. If you know it then you can do it by this way. :)